# How to use a property that was set in a custom action?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I want to set a property in a custom action and use it in the standard custom action "util:User" afterwards. But no matter where I put the property in my wxs-file, I always get "error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol"

Details:
In my setup I want to add a new user by using util:User. The user should be added to the group "Power Users" by using util:GroupRef. No Problem so far. Unfortunately the group names are language dependent. In german "Power Users" is "Hauptbenutzer". So I want to look up the well known SID S-1-5-32-547 in a custom action, set a property in this custom action by calling MsiSetProperty and then use the property for util:GroupRef.

As far as I understand, the property must be declared somewhere in the wxs-file.
In the examples I found, the property was never declared as follows (but I also tried that):

```
<Property Id="TextSID" Value="Power Users" />
```

In the examples there always was a custom action to set the property, like:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetTextSID"
  Property="TextSID"
  Value="Power Users"
  Return="check" />
```

My problem is, that the creation of the user fails to "compile" because the property "TextSID" is not known:

```
  <Component Id="CreateUser" Guid="Some GUID here in my original wxs file">
    <util:User Id="UserUser" 
               Name="User" Password="Password"
               CanNotChangePassword="yes" PasswordNeverExpires="yes">
      <util:GroupRef Id="TextSID" />
    </util:User>
  </Component>
```

I have never done a custom action before and I'm a new to WiX and MSI, so any idea would be very welcome.

Regards
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time.

I stared at my XML for hours before I posted this question, just to find the answer immediately after my post :-(

My only problem was, that it is not possible to reference to something that isn't there. In this case the "util:Group" was missing.